# C# Reverse a Bit Shifting

Tags: c#, .net, bit-shift

Is there a way to reverse the following bitshift so I can extract the values of 6972307 / 1 / 2 / 3? If not, I only really "need" the (1 << 17) value.

```
long shifted = (6972307 << 22) | (1 << 17) | (2 << 12) | 3;
```

Additional background.

The value shifted by 17 has a maximum value of 6 and the shift by 12 has a maximum value of 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of shifts and `ANDs`:

```
var v1 = shifted & 0xfff; //3
var v2 = (shifted >> 12) & 0x1f; //2
var v3 = (shifted >> 17) & 0x1f; //1
var v4 = (shifted >> 22);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can accomplish that by right-shifting the result and masking out unwanted bits:

```
long top = shifted >> 22;
long part1 = (shifted >> 17) & 7;
long part2 = (shifted >> 12) & 31;
long part3 = shifted & 3;
```

Note that you might not get the correct result for the top part depending on the number of bits used by a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your 6972307 to long prior shift so the expression will look like:

```
long shifted = ((long)6972307 << 22) | (1 << 17) | (2 << 12) | 3;
```

Thus you will store all bits correctly in long variable, not in an int variable. After that you can get your 6972307 value back with right shift

```
long shiftedBack = shifted >> 22;
```

However note that the value which you are shifting to the left(6972307 in your example) still has to have some maximum. Above that maximum 22-bit shift will cut off some bits and you will be unable to shift back correctly.